# How do i convert custom hook into HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, higher-order-functions

I made custom hook and used in interceptors which is not react component.it's javascript function so i got this error-

> *Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component*.

And this is unfortunate because it prevents us from using newer hook-based modules in our older class-based components and regular javascript functions.
So now i want to be convert custom hook into HOC.

```js
const useLoader = props => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(props);

  return [
    loading ? <Loader /> : null,
    () => setLoading(true), // show loader
    () => setLoading(false) // hideLoader
  ];
};
export default useLoader;
```

How can i do that i have never write HOC.

[Here is the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-loader-jtfqp?file=/src/index.js)

---

So the requirement is when i click on proceed button loader will be visible on the screen on api call after getting the response then only loader will disappear and navigate to the next page.

[image]

Here is updated code where i have updated with HOC but 
loader seems works only first time when i load the page.
what i am missing here ?

[Updated with HOC - codeSandboax](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-loader-forked-ragi-7pps1?file=/src/components/Home.js)

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an interceptor which is not react function component. so when i am trying to use custom hook (**useLoader** ) in my interceptor then i got the errror **Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**
so we can use custom hook into regular function. so that is why i want to convert custom hook into HOC.
---

Comment: What interceptor/regular function is it? Could you give us an example?

Comment: Yes i have added code link @Hangindev

Comment: Oh your idea is to use it in `axios`'s interceptors?

Comment: @Hangindev yes,  This is not good to write on every component loader true or false it should be handle on globally right

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```js
const LoaderHOC = ({ Component }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(props);

  const toggleLoading = () => {
    setLoading(!loading)
  }

  return (
    loading ? <Loader/> : <Component toggleLoading={toggleLoading}/>
  )
};
export default useLoader;
```

I think you will get an idea.

Comment: Can you please fork my code update it. because i have tired out my own it's not working for me.

Comment: Here is the updated code - using HOC 
https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-loader-forked-ragi-7pps1?file=/src/components/Home.js
------
but the problem is loader works only first time load the page